# Parity of Harmonic oscillator in 2 and 3 dimensions: the case of $l_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, harmonic-oscillator, parity

From doing exercises and trying to understand their solutions, i figured in two dimensions, not all values of $l_z$ can be taken by the particles (this is to conserve parity). For example, for n=0, the only l possible is 0, so $l_z=0$. For n=1, l=(1,0), but it's z projection can only be $l_z=\pm$1, so l=0 is discarted. n=2 means $l_z=(\pm$2,0) , n=3 we got $l_z=(\pm3,\pm1)$ and so on. In three dimensions though, all values of the projections are available. Why can $l_z$ take all values in 3D and not 2D?

Comment: *The problem in 3D i'm working with, requires me to work in the center of mass reference system.* It's unclear what you mean by this or how it relates to anything else here. *Is it that or do "parity problems" vanish in 3D?* What do you mean by "Is it that?"

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

$\let\phi=\varphi \let\dag=\dagger \def\half{{\textstyle{1 \over 2}}}
\def\PD#1#2{{\partial#1 \over \partial#2}} \def\ket#1{|#1\rangle} $
Your question can't be answered in a simple way. It implies a rather
deep matter falling under the title "Group theory and quantum
mecahnics". IMO it's very far from a "homework-and-exercise". I'll try
to give an answer but I don't know how far you'll be able to follow
it.

To begin with, your approach requires some qualifications. First:
I wouldn't use $l_z$ for angular momentum in 2D. The $z$ dimension
simply *doesn't exist*. There are just two coordinates, $x$ and $y$,
and two conjugate momenta $p_x$, $p_y$. All operators are expressed as
functions thereof. In a more sophisticated jargon, those four
operators generate the full algebra of observables for your quantum
system.

Hamiltonian is written
$$H = {1 \over 2m}\,(p_x^2 + p_y^2) + \half k\,(x^2 + y^2).$$

> not all values of $l_z$ can be taken by the particles (this is to
>   conserve parity).

Surely parity plays an important rôle but not the one you're
saying (see later).

Let's look for conserved quantities. There are two. The first is what
you called $l_z$ and I prefer to name $L$. It's the angular momentum
*in plane* $(x,y)$ around origin. Its expression as an operator is
$$L = x\,p_y - y\,p_x.$$
In Schrödinger representation 
$$L = -i\hbar \left(\!x\,\PD{}y - y\,\PD{}x\!\right) = 
-i\hbar\,\PD{}\phi.$$
It's not exactly trivial to verify that $[L,H]=0$, but it can be done, using commutation relation among canonical variables.

The second is $P$, which I'll define as 
$$P:\ x \mapsto -x,\ y \mapsto y.\tag1$$
Some notes are necessary.

1) I've defined $P$ as $x$-inversion, not as combined inversion of $x$
and $y$. There is a difference between 2D and 3D cases. In 2D the
simultaneous inversion of both coordinates is obtained by a rotation
of an angle $\pi$, and as a rotation is already included in $L$
symmetry. On the contrary in 3D the inversion of all three coordinates isn't a rotation and must explicitly added as a further symmetry.

2) To completely define $P$ we must also specify its action on momenta:
$$P:\ p_x \mapsto -p_x,\ p_y \mapsto p_y.\tag2$$
It's important to observe that (1) and (2) together leave commutation
relations invariant. This is necessary if $P$ is to be a unitary
operator. It's easy to verify that $P$ leaves $H$ invariant, i.e.
$$P\,H\,P^\dag = H \qquad P\,H = H\,P \qquad [P,H] = 0.$$

3) In place of reflecting about $y$-axis we could reflect about $x$ as
well, or about any other axis through origin. These are all different
symmetries, but each one is obtained from any other by combining it
with rotations. So in a sense they're all equivalent.

4) A distinction is needed between the operation of *space inversion*
and its eigenvalue. Parity has a special property: as a symmetry
operation it's represented by a unitary operator: 
$P\,P^\dag = P^\dag P = I$. But if $P$ is applied twice it reproduces
the initial state and observables: $P^2 = I$. Then $P^\dag = P$ ($P$
is hermitian) and its only eigenvalues are $p=\pm1$. A state belonging
to $+1$ is said *even*, one with $p=-1$ is *odd*.

---

We've encountered thus far 3 important observables: $H$, $L$, $P$ and
ve've seen that both $L$ and $P$ commute with $H$. Let's add now that
$L$ and $P$ don't commute:
$$P\,L\,P = -L \qquad P\,L = -L\,P.$$
How could we use $H$, $L$, $P\,$'s eigenvalues to classify states? How
could we discover the known degeneracy of $H\,$?

A general theorem ensures us that both couples: $(H,L)$ and $(H,P)$
share a complete set (a base) of eigenvectors. So two classifications
are allowed: $\ket{e_n,l_n}$ and $\ket{e_n,p_n}$, where $e_n$ is n-th
$H$ eigenvalue, $l_n$ n-th $L$ eigenvalue (up to an $\hbar$ factor),
$p_n$ is n-th $P$ eigenvalue, and $n$ runs over integers. We can't
expect instead that a base of common eigenkets exists, something like
$\ket{e_n,l_n,p_n}$.

Note however that the cited theorem doesn't say anything about
degeneracy, meaning that for two different $n$'s we have $e_n=e_{n'}$.
But the following may be proven:

*Theorem*. For any $\ket{e_n,l_n}$ with $l_n\ne0$ there is $n'$ such
that $e_n=e_{n'}$, $l_n=-l_{n'}$.

*Proof*. Define
$$\ket\xi = P\,\ket{e_n,l_n}.$$
Then
$$H\,\ket\xi = H\,P\,\ket{e_n,l_n} =  
P\,H\,\ket{e_n,l_n} = e_n\,P\,\ket{e_n,l_n} = e_n\,\ket\xi.$$
This shows that $\ket\xi$ is an eigenket of $H$ for the eigenvalue $e_n$.
Moreover
$$L\,\ket\xi = L\,P\,\ket{e_n,l_n} =  
-P\,L\,\ket{e_n,l_n} = - l_n\,P\,\ket{e_n,l_n} = -l_n\,\ket\xi$$
and this shows that $\ket\xi$ is an eigenket of $L$ for the
eigenvalue $-l_n$.

So $\ket\xi$ is a simultaneous eigenket of $H$, $L$ for eigenvalues
$e_n$, $-l_n$. If $l_n\ne0$ it's a different eigenket than $\ket{e_n,l_n}$ and we have shown that there is an $n'\ne n$ such that 
$$P\,\ket{e_n,l_n} = \ket{e_{n'},l_{n'}}.$$
*qed*.

---

Our theorem has proven that a twofold degeneracy exists, for opposite
eigenvalues of $L$. But we know the 2D harmonic oscillator has a
higher degeneracy. Where does it come from? To answer a much richer
symmetry must be introduced. Since this post has already been rather
long I stop here and defer the complete proof to an edit to be
expected tomorrow or later.

Comment: I am sorry for the ridiculously late reply. Thank you for the answer. The solution to the problem comes from reconstructing the solutions to Shrödinger's equation as power series multiplied by a gaussian exponential (for vanishing purposes). One finds that, since the polar coord. Laplacian gives you m dependance, the coefficients of the power series depend on $m^2$. Comparing these with even/odd polynomials (you can directly do it with hermite, but it's not necessary), you find those values of m. Makes more sense once you do it